# Check is innerHTMl inside contains any HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how do i check whether the inner HTML contains only Text  or any tags inside .

for example here

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/media/1020/phone.png"></a>
```

this anchor tag inside there is an image tag is here i have to skip this scenario , where as

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Hello</a>
```

if this .innerHTML will return only Hello text , the above one returns the entire image tag like this `<img src="/media/1020/phone.png">` .

so i need only with texts inside directly , if any html tag inside i have to throw error , any help

Answer (score 4):

You might check if every `childNode` of the parent is a text node:

```js
const as = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];
as.forEach(a => {
  console.log(
    [...a.childNodes].every(node => node.nodeType === 3)
  );
});
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/media/1020/phone.png"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Hello</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Hello<img src="/media/1020/phone.png">Hello</a>
```

Comment: FYI, `NodeList` has a `forEach` method these days ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Hey may i know what does node.noteType means here?

Comment: @Kannan It's `nodeType`, and it's a number that reflects the type of the node, with a full list and explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: good answer using modern javascript.  Except the fact that you do not need to create an array with nodes because you can use `forEach` directly on the nodeList. Anyway, good job

Answer (score 0):

As yourself said i need direct text so i haven't considered the text inside these tags p,H1 etc. Here is my logic.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").each(function() {
       if($(this).text() != '') {
          console.log($(this).text());
       }
       else {
          console.log("Error");
      }
    })
});
```

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/n6pe5fx4/15/

Comment: Consider `<a>Text <img></a>`